# Find derivative of $u = \sin(y^2 + u)$ using implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find $\frac{du}{dy}$, when $u = \sin(y^2 + u)$, using chain rule and expanding I get:

$1 = (2y\frac{du}{dy} + 1) \cos(y^2 + u)$

$2y \cos(y^2 + u)\frac{du}{dy} + \cos(y^2 + u) = 1$

$2y \cos(y^2 + u)\frac{du}{dy} = 1- \cos(y^2 + u)$

$\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{1 - \cos(y^2 + u)}{2y \cos(y^2 + u)}$

Since this was wrong, I massaged it a bit more to:

$\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{\sec(y^2 + u) - 1}{2y}$

Still wrong... But what am I doing wrong, wolfram alpha seems to agree with me...

Comment: Are you trying to find $\frac{du}{dy}$ or $\frac{dy}{du}$?  If you want $\frac{du}{dy}$ your first step should look like $$\frac{du}{dy} = \left(2y + \frac{du}{dy}\right)\cos\left(y^{2} + u\right).$$

Comment: Your first line should have $\frac{dy}{du}$ not $\frac{du}{dy}$

Comment: Follow-up Q: Suppose $y=0$ when $ u=0.$ Show that $y'(0)=0$ and that $y'(u)$ is continuous at $u=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking derivative towards $u$ w.r.t.$y$ is not $1$, but should be $\frac{d u}{d y}$

Thus, it instead should be:

$$\frac{du}{dy}=\cos(y^2 + u)(2y + \frac{du}{dy})$$
$$\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{2y\cos(y^2+u)}{1-\cos(y^2 + u)}$$

Comment: Another form would be $du/dy = y \left(\cot ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(u+y^2\right)\right)-1\right)$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze yep, this could be a more compact expression, will incorporate it in my answer. Thanks

Comment: You might wish to see my answer to this question below.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I'm checking your answer: I wonder do we want to consider the range of the image/domain when we do the inverse e.g. When doing $\sin^{-1}$, the value of $(u+y^2)$ becomes restricted within $[\pi/2, \pi/2]$ - if we could take care of this, I think it is a good idea/answer.

Answer (score 1):

i have $$u'=\cos(y^2+u)(2y+u')$$ therefore $$u'=\frac{2y\cos(y^2+u)}{1-\cos(y^2+u)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Assuming that $u=u(y)$ and calling $u'=du/dy$ we have:

$$u'=(2y+u')\cos(y^2+u)\to u'=\frac{2y\cos(y^2+u)}{1-\cos(y^2+u)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The expressions given so far can be said to suffer from the fact that the variables $y$ and $u$ are not separated. Although this was not requested in the OP we provide the solution with this additional feature.

The trick is to use $y$ as the dependent variable and $u$ as the independent one.

Solving

$$u = sin(u + y^2)$$

for $y$ gives

$$y = \pm \sqrt{\sin ^{-1}(u)-u}$$

Now

$$ \frac{\text{dy}}{\text{du}}=\pm\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-1}{2 \sqrt{\sin ^{-1}(u)-u}}$$

inverting gives finally

$$\frac{\text{du}}{\text{dy}}=\pm\frac{2 \sqrt{1-u^2} \sqrt{\sin ^{-1}(u)-u}}{1-\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

This expression can be used, for example, to study the implicit function $u(y)$ close to $u = 0$. Which is found to be

$$u(y)\simeq \sqrt[3]{6 y^2}$$